# Sed Append Line

Tags: linux, sed

Does sed have a command to append a line after a matched line? I tried searching around but was a bit confused with the results.

Basiclly I want it to match

```
#address=/doubleclick.net/127.0.0.1
```

And add a line below it like

```
#address=/doubleclick.net/127.0.0.1

address=/anotherurl/ipaddress
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `a`(append) command in `sed`:

```
$ sed -i '/^#address=\/doubleclick.net\/127.0.0.1$/a\
> address=/anotherurl/ipaddress' file.txt
```

Or you can use `s`(substitute) command:

```
$ sed -i 's@^#address=/doubleclick.net/127.0.0.1$@&\naddress=/anotherurl/ipaddress@' file.txt
```

**Note:** `$` and `>` are bash prompt.

Comment: You hit **`<Enter>`** after a\, bash doesn't run immediately, it waits for more another `'`(single quote) to match the first `'`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo "#address=/doubleclick.net/127.0.0.1"|
sed '\|#address=/doubleclick.net/127.0.0.1|a\address=/anotherurl/ipaddress' 
#address=/doubleclick.net/127.0.0.1
address=/anotherurl/ipaddress
```

You can use any delimiter you like in an address by prepending a `\` i.e. `\|...|` for the substitute command the `\` is not necessary.

If you want a blank line then some text following the match, use:

```
echo "#address=/doubleclick.net/127.0.0.1"|
sed '\|#address=/doubleclick.net/127.0.0.1|a\\naddress=/anotherurl/ipaddress' 
#address=/doubleclick.net/127.0.0.1

address=/anotherurl/ipaddress
```

Comment: I'm having problems adding this into a script. It doesn't replace it in the script but running it manually it does